# How do you link a time stamp to a cell using a userform button control?

Tags: vba, excel, timer, stopwatch

Hello fellow VB Developers/Users/Hobbyists. How are You?

I have a Userform that has two buttons:

1. Start
2. Stop

When I press `Start`, I would like it to record the current time in the format `dd/mm/yy hh:nn:ss` in a specific column.

Then when I press the `Stop` Button I would like it to record the time again in the cell next to it.

Then if I press `Start` again, I would like it to record below the first cell's current record.  Basically I am building a timer to record data to see how long certain tasks take.

I will post the excel file and provide more information where necessary.

Thanks for any help provided.

**CURRENT CODE**

```
Public runTimer As Double
Public startTime As Date
Dim counter As Date

Sub setStart()
    counter = 0
    startTime = Now
    runTimer = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)

    Application.OnTime runTimer, "setStart", , True

    Set myTime = Sheet4.Range("F1")
    Set timeRng = Sheet4.Range("C8:C100")
    i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(timeRng)
    i = i + 1

    Cells(i, "C") = myTime
    Sheet4.Cells(i, "C").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss"

    If i >= 2 Then
        Cells(i, "D8") = Cells(i, "C8") - Cells(i - 1, "C8")
        Sheet4.Cells(i, "C").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss"
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = False
End Sub

Sub setStop()
    Application.OnTime runTimer, "setStop", , True

    Set myTime = Sheet4.Range("F1")
    Set timeRng = Sheet4.Range("D8:D100")
    i = WorksheetFunction.CountA(timeRng)
    i = i + 1

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Cells(i, "D") = myTime
    Sheet4.Cells(i, "D").NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss"
End Sub
```

---

Thank you for the feedback and suggestions.

both of these work great.  I am still having an issue of recording the data in specific worksheets within the code.  I do not want to use the current worksheet.  I would like it to be sheet1 and start the recording in cell "A8"  as opposed to cell "A2"

Thanks.

Comment: I would definitely like to see your workbook.

Comment: You can replace ActiveSheet with Range("Sheet1") and I presume you have content in the rows above A8 so these should adjust. If not, insert something on the workbook_Open event to set content above where you need to start

Answer (score 1):

I've done something similar to keep track of how long SQL and MDX queries take when run from Excel applications. Users' sense of how long something takes (it took 5 minutes!) and what actually happened don't always agree. I need to know how long certain things take to either defend the application or understand what I need to optimize.

I set up a sheet to mimic your example. The headers in row 1:

```
Start Time     Stop Time     Elapsed Time
```

I also have a start button and a stop button. I assigned `setStart` to the start button and `setStop` to the stop button.

**The code:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub setStart()
    Dim NextRow As Long
    NextRow = GetLastRow("A") + 1

    With Range("a" & NextRow)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss"
    End With
End Sub

Sub setStop()
    Dim NextRow As Long
    NextRow = GetLastRow("B") + 1

    With Range("b" & NextRow)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss"
    End With
    calcElapsedTime (NextRow)
End Sub

Sub calcElapsedTime(NextRow As Long)
    With Range("c" & NextRow)
        .Formula = "=B" & NextRow & "-A" & NextRow
        .NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    End With
End Sub

Function GetLastRow(ColumnLetter As String) As Long
    GetLastRow = Range(ColumnLetter & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```

Note that I am not checking to see if the starts and stops are done in the correct sequence. If you press start 3 times, it will continue to add values in the start column that don't have matching stop times, which will obviously foul up the elapsed times. If the code I've provided is what you're after, you'll need to add that kind of logic to your app.

Answer (score 0):

I like the simplicity of @Head of Catering 's answer. You might change it slightly to a single button so that you can only start or stop depending upon which needs to occur.

You could color format the button text as well as a visual reminder.

Just a couple additions and run startTimer on CommandButton1

```
    Option Explicit
Sub startTimer()
If ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Caption = "START" Then
        setStart
    Else
        setStop
    End If
End Sub
Sub setStart()
    Dim NextRow As Long
    NextRow = GetLastRow("A") + 1

    With Range("a" & NextRow)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss"
    End With
   ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Caption = "STOP"
End Sub

Sub setStop()
    Dim NextRow As Long
    NextRow = GetLastRow("B") + 1

    With Range("b" & NextRow)
        .Value = Now
        .NumberFormat = "yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm:ss"
    End With
    calcElapsedTime (NextRow)
    ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.Caption = "START"
End Sub

Sub calcElapsedTime(NextRow As Long)
    With Range("c" & NextRow)
        .Formula = "=B" & NextRow & "-A" & NextRow
        .NumberFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
    End With
End Sub

Function GetLastRow(ColumnLetter As String) As Long
    GetLastRow = Range(ColumnLetter & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End Function
```